# How to adapt Pascal triangle with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap v3 adapt each level of Pascal Triangle. Each level must adapt to width according each device, level 1 one single adaptive box, level 2 3 single adaptive box, etc.

Comment: this site is not code writing service

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: `$('level').bootstrap(3).pascal()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a posible way to make the grid and the pascal triangle

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <input id="tam" max="6" min="1" type="number" value="1"/>
        <input id="btnTam" type="button" value="Generar triangulo" onclick="trianguloPascal()"/>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div id="c1-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c1-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c2-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c2-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c3-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c3-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c4-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c4-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c5-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c5-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c6-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c6-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c7-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c7-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c8-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c8-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c9-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c9-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c10-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c10-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c11-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c11-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="c12-1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-2" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-3" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-4" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-5" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-6" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-7" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-8" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-9" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-10" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-11" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
        <div id="c12-12" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 "></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function trianguloPascal() {

        n = document.getElementById("tam").value;
        x = 0;
        var pasc = new Array(n);
        var cadena = new Array(n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            pasc[i] = new Array(n);
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
                if (document.getElementById("c" + i + "-" + j) != undefined)
                    document.getElementById("c" + i + "-" + j).innerHTML = "";
            }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = x; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (j == x || j == 0) {
                    pasc[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    pasc[i][j] = pasc[i - 1][j] + pasc[i - 1][j - 1];
                }
            }
            x++;

            iCol = n - i;


            for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {

                document.getElementById("c" + (i + 1) + "-" + iCol).innerHTML = pasc[i][j];
                iCol += 2;
            }

            //        cadena += "</br>";

        }


    }
</script>
```

The whole page can be viewed in:
http://nath.site40.net/Pascal.html

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer

```
<script>    
    function iniciar()
    {
        var filas = document.getElementById('num_filas').value;
        tabla(filas);    
    }
    function factorial(p) 
    {
        f = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= p; i++) 
            f *= i;
        return f;
    }

    function combinaciones(m, n) 
    {
        if (n <= m) 
        {
            var dividendo1 = factorial(m);
            var divisor1 = factorial(m - n);
            var divisor = factorial(n);
            var dividendo = dividendo1 / divisor1;
            var combinacion = Math.round(dividendo / divisor);
            return combinacion;
        } 
        else return;
    }

    function tabla(filas) 
    {
        var filas = parseInt(filas);
        var valor = 0;
        var matriz = new Array(filas*filas);
        var cont = 0;
        var div;
        for (m = 0; m < filas; m++) 
        {
            for (n = 0; n < filas; n++) 
            {
                if (n <= m) 
                {
                    valor = combinaciones(m, n);
                    matriz[cont] = valor;
                    cont = cont + 1;
                } 
                else 
                    break;
            }
        }

        cont = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i < filas ; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < filas ; j++)
            {
                div=document.getElementById('triangulo');
                div.innerHTML += matriz[cont];
                div.innerHTML += "    ";
                cont = cont + 1;
                if(i == j)
                    break;
            }
            document.getElementById('triangulo').innerHTML += '<br>';
        }

    }
</script>
```

for the whole site visit [enter link description here](https://www.googledrive.com/host/0Bwmvl3QwdUKFMkVPa1VyVXE2Qjg)